# weird - mysql's sql::SQLException is not caught by its type, but is caught as std::exception and cast back successfully

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, exception, shared-libraries

I am using mysql c++ connector with this (a bit simplified) code.

```
try
{
    statement->setString(1, word);
    statement->executeUpdate();
}
catch( sql::SQLException& e )
{
    // I don't get here
    return sqlerrno_to_error_code( e.getErrorCode() );
}
catch( std::exception& e )
{
    // I do get here and the cast works
    sql::SQLException& sqle = (sql::SQLException&) e;
    return sqlerrno_to_error_code( sqle.getErrorCode() );
}
```

The connector is supposed to throw the sql::SQLException which derives from std::exception and has some additional methods like `getErrorCode()`.

The exception thrown is caught in the second `catch` block, but can be cast to (and used as)`sql::SQLException` successfully.

Even more weird is that a similar code in a different executable catches `sql::SQLException` as expected. The difference between them is that the first one is in a shared object (.so) that is loaded with `dlopen()`.

RHEL 5.7 32 bit, gcc 4.1.2

Answer (score 4):

See the note for [`dynamic_cast`, `throw`, `typeid` don't work with shared libraries](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/faq.html#dso) on the GCC Frequently Asked Questions page.

Because you are using `dlopen()`, you need to link your executable with the `-E` flag (or pass
`-Wl,-E` to `g++` if `g++` is invoking the linker) and pass the `RTLD_GLOBAL` flag to `dlopen()`.

Comment: thanks, found it meanwhile but it does not seem to help so far. Could it depend on the compiler version? mine is 4.1.2

Comment: @davka: The problem could be that a different compiler was used to compile the MySQL Connector/C++ library, because the compiler ABI is implementation-specific. Try recompiling the Connector/C++ library from source using the same compiler (go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/ and choose "Source Code" from the Platform combo box).

Comment: good point. I don't think we can recompile the connector - we request clients to install mysqll as a pre-req, but it's worth checking with which version it was compiled

Comment: @davka: Are you sure you can't recompile the Connector/C++ library and distribute the custom built lib with your executable? I don't believe that Connector/C++ is installed with MySQL, and in any case, you can configure the linker to link to a relative path, relying on `/lib/ld-linux.so`'s $ORIGIN/rpath support to make sure that your custom-built Connector/C++ lib is used.

Comment: you are correct it isn't. This is a legal issue actually - whether we can distribute it even though the customer is the one who purchases the license.